# Span at bottom of display:table-cell and vertical align

Tags: css

I have a div which is I have made `display:table-cell`, because I want the `p` to be `vertical-align:middle` inside.

But when my `span` that I want at the bottom of the div dissappears when I do this (goes outside).

Is this possible with the current code?

https://jsfiddle.net/bpuoxsvo/

```css
.table1
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:table;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
}

.table1 > p
{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table > span
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;

  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;

  background-color:blue;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="table1">
    <p>
      Table 1
    </p>
    <span class="color"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this what you're going for? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWMLaZ

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, thank you, if you want you can post it as answer and I will accept it. Maybe a little explanation would be appreciated too :D

Comment: cool will do, just wasn't sure if that was your end goal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.table` in your CSS selector needs to be `.table1`, then you want to add `position: relative` to `.table1` so that the absolutely positioned element will be positioned *relative* to `.table1`. Then give the span `left: 0` so it starts at the left side of the table instead of to the right of the `p`

```css
.table1
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:table;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}

.table1 > p
{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table1 > span
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;

  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color:blue;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="table1">
    <p>
      Table 1
    </p>
    <span class="color"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```